# simple toggle hook in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having problem abstracting my toggle function out to a hook. I can make the toggle right but something is wrong in this hook code:

```
import { useState, useCallback } from "react";

const useToggle = (initialValue = false) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);

  const toggle = useCallback((defaultValue) => {
    defaultValue !== undefined
      ? setValue(defaultValue) //set true or false
      : setValue((value) => !value); //if param is not supplied, toggle the value
  }, []);

  return [value, toggle];
};

export default useToggle;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-swartz-ztdfb?file=/src/App.js

what's wrong?

Comment: Hi can you add some more information, like show us the component that you are using this toggle()

and also one of my conclusion is that you not need to use useCallback hook

Comment: @akibo Your custom hook is fine. See my answer to better understand why the difference in your implementation and article's implementation.

Comment: @akibo Look at this link and see if this is what you are looking for?                                   https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-wilbur-wbu8k?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On writing this code:

```
<button onClick={toggle}>toggle</button>
```

You actually are passing the event object to `toggle` function.

```
onClick={(event) => toggle(event)}
// Same
onClick={toggle}
```

And in your custom hook, you have the condition `defaultValue !== undefined` which will result in a truthy value.

Therefore you should do:

```
<button onClick={() => toggle()}>toggle</button>
```

And for your notice you can just use `useReducer` instead of custom hook:

```
const [value,toggle] = useReducer(p=>!p, false);
```

Example of `useToggle`

```
const useToggle = (initialValue = false) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);
  const toggle = useCallback(() => setValue((value) => !value), []);
  return [value, toggle];
};
```

Comment: why would I need to use an arrow function? I copy the source from here https://joshwcomeau.com/snippets/react-hooks/use-toggle, is there any error in the article?

Comment: Because again, `onClick` passes the event object: `onClick={(e) => toggle(e)}` is same as writing `onClick={toggle}`, `onClick` callback passes `e` object.

Comment: why use useReducer not useState?

Comment: There is no error in the article, you have an error with `defaultValue !== undefined` as I explained in the answer

Comment: You can use whatever you like, why should you use `useState` and make a custom hook from it, unless as it seems you trying to defend from a non boolean value :\

Comment: how is this not an error? https://i.imgur.com/KoV5f5E.png

Comment: I write hook because toggle function is common and it can be used elsewhere, isn't that the idea of using a hook?

Comment: Because in his custom hook implementation there is no condition on the value `defaultValue !== undefined` as I said three times

Comment: ok I got it, so if I want to add param for default value (either true or false), what's the proper way to write the hook?

Comment: @DennisVash You are right about event object. I think he needs to understand param being passed. This is being set and being converted to string via toString(). Please see my answer!

Comment: "what's the proper way to write the hook?" is an opinioned question.

Comment: how to avoid using an arrow function to call the toggle()?

Comment: then how to set false? create another function in the hook? imagine a toggle which you can't set true or false but only can toggle, how limited

Comment: initialValue !== defaultValue, why you passing a value to `toggle`??

Comment: Ive added an example, not sure if you follow

Comment: ok let me clarify what I need. 1. a state of true and false 2. a toggle function 3. a function that can set true or false. that's why I need to pass a param to toggle function like toggle(true) or toggle(false)

Comment: So return three values: `{state,setState,toggle}` ....

Comment: yup but would lose the useCallback benefit, that's why I rather pass the param to one function.

Comment: So make `useCallback` for each function..... I don't understand what you saying, anyways this discussion is too long for me, I think I stop here, your question is answered

Comment: so you're saying passing a param to toggle is wrong? anyway, it works, thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

The difference in your code and the article is that article has this code:

```
React.useCallback(()
```

Notice `()`. It doesn't take any parameter. So even when onClick passes the event it is being ignored in the article code.

But in your code you are using like this:

```
useCallback((defaultValue)
```

Here `defaultValue` becomes event object and that's why you see `status: [object Object]` in your output when you click on toggle button because event object is being converted to string in this call:

```
status: {open.toString()}
```

Hope this clarifies!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I don't understand what you're trying to achieve but something like this would toggle between true/false along with being much more simple?

```
 const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

  const toggleButtonHandler = () => {
    setToggle(!toggle);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>Status: {toggle.toString()}</p>
      <button onClick={setToggle(false)}>false</button>
      <button onClick={toggleButtonHandler}>toggle</button>
    </div>
  );
```